# How can I use Qt 5 with ROS catkin?

Tags: ros, qt5

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm able to use qt_ros, but it creates package depending on Qt4, but I need Qt 5.1 or older to use QSerialPort. How can I do it? Is it a bad idea?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/135916/how-can-i-use-qt-5-with-ros-catkin?/) by [Rr](https://answers.ros.org/users/2748/rr/) on ROS Answers with karma: 15 on 2014-03-05

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

please see this [question](http://answers.ros.org/question/84821/how-to-use-serial-port-in-ros/)
and change

```
find_package(Qt4 COMPONENTS QtCore QtGui)
```

to

```
find_package(Qt5 COMPONENTS QtCore QtGui)
```

---

Originally posted by [Hamid Didari](https://answers.ros.org/users/6486/hamid-didari/) with karma: 1769 on 2014-03-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Rr](https://answers.ros.org/users/2748/rr/) on 2014-03-05**:
I tried, but it says

"CMake Error at /home/roman/Qt/5.2.1/gcc/lib/cmake/Qt5/Qt5Config.cmake:3 (message):
Qt5 requires at least CMake version 2.8.9
Call Stack (most recent call first):
test/CMakeLists.txt:9 (find_package)".

ROS Hydro Medusa uses CMake 2.8.3...

**Comment by [OzzieTheHead](https://answers.ros.org/users/13406/ozziethehead/) on 2016-02-02**:
This was not possible in Qt5.0 and you had to call find_package() seperately like:
find_package(Qt5Widgets)
find_package(Qt5Declarative)
https://www.kdab.com/using-cmake-with-qt-5/